# How can I traverse backwards in my Unordered Array?

Tags: java, arrays, iterator, computer-science, unordered

I am working on an assignment and I am currently stuck on trying to go through my array from top down. This array is #1 based, therefore it starts on 1 rather then 0.

To test my iterator, I made an accompanying reverse method that goes through the array from the currentSize and gos down the array, printing out every object in it. But it seems to not execute the method. I am assuming that there might be something wrong with my iterator or they way I write my reverse method.

Ultimatley, I need for the array to be able totraverse backwards when the tester calls on the iterator.

Here is how the things are being added to the array:

```
public void addFirst(E obj) {
    if(currentSize==maxSize)
        growStrorage();

    if(isEmpty())
        storage[1]=obj;

    for(int i=1; i>currentSize+1; i++){
        storage[i+1]=storage[i];
    }

    storage[1]=obj;
    modCounter++;
    currentSize++;
}
```

Here is the reverse method (This is was made as a tester method to help solve my issue) :

```
public void reverseList() {

        for(int i=currentSize; i>=1;i--)
            System.out.println(storage[i]);


    }
```

Here is my showMe method as requested (this was also made as a tester method to help solve my issues):

```
public void showMe(){

    for(int i=1; i<=currentSize; i++)
        System.out.print(i+" ");


}
```

Here is my iterator:

```
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return new IteratorHelper();
}

private class IteratorHelper <E>implements Iterator <E>{

    private int iterIndex;
    long stateCheck;

    public IteratorHelper(){
        iterIndex=1;
        stateCheck=modCounter;
    }

    public boolean hasNext(){
        if(stateCheck !=modCounter){
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        }

        return iterIndex<=currentSize;
    }

    public E next(){
        if(!hasNext())
            throw new NoSuchElementException();

            return (E)storage[iterIndex++];

    }
```

And here is the tester:

```
 for(int i=1; i <= 10; i++)
        list.addFirst(new Integer(i));  
    System.out.println("Current size of list: (should be 10)" 
        + list.size()); 

 //My code 
   System.out.println("Now showing what is in Array..");
       list.showMe();
       System.out.println("\n");  
   System.out.println("Now reversing Array..");
    list.reverseList();


  *******  System.out.println("Now using the iterator, should print " *******
        + "10 .. 1");            
    for(int x : list)
        System.out.print(x + " ");
    System.out.println();
```

****** == the place where I am having issue with my code

Here is the print:

```
 Should print 1 .. 10
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 

   Now removing them all
   Current size of list: (should be zero) 0
    Current size of list: (should be 10)10
   Now showing what is in Array..
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 

   Now reversing Array..
   null
   null
   null
   null
   null
   null
   null
   null
   null
   10
  Now using the iterator, should print 10 .. 1
  10 ERROR java.lang.NullPointerException
  java.lang.NullPointerException
    at data_structures.P1Tester.runTests(P1Tester.java:49)
    at data_structures.P1Tester.<init>(P1Tester.java:14)
    at data_structures.P1Tester.main(P1Tester.java:103)
```

Comment: Your reverse list method only prints out the index, not any value at that index.

Comment: @BrettOkken thanks for pointing out, I just changed it. But still no change in the behavior.

Comment: Your reverse list does not do anything other than print out stuff. It does not actually reverse the order of the entries.

Comment: @BrettOkken my reverse method was only intended as a tester on my iterator. I used it to check if my iterator was having issues reverse traversing.

Comment: What does `growStorage` do?

Comment: @BrettOkken the growStorage is a method that doubles the array size if there is not enough room in the array when the user adds more objs.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, when travering in reverse, it seems like your for-loop is not correct. I'm assuming it should be `i >= 0` instead of `i<=1` which is never true. Furthermore you should probably print out something more than `i` which is only the index.

```
public void reverseList() {

    for(int i=currentSize; i >= 0;i--)
        System.out.println(i);

}
```

Another place in your code where you have swapped `<` and `>`

Also, this code will set storage[2] = storage[1], storage[3] = storage[2] and etc, which means storage[i] = storage[1] for all i. Fundamental bug. It should probably be something like:

```
for(int i = currentSize; i >= 1; i++){
    storage[i+1]=storage[i];
}
```

Comment: Good point! I accidently switched the less than sign and greater sign, but the stop point needs to be 1 because the 0 index is not used in this program. I also switched the print to print out the object at the index. But now the items are printing 9 null objects and a 10. Where before the reverse method is executed, 10 objects are added to the array.

Comment: @ShermanBachar Okay, glad that helped. What do you print out instead of i inside the for-loop ? storage[i] I presume?

Comment: @ShermanBachar Can you show us the code for the .showMe()-method as it might do something buggy before the reverse call.

Comment: Yea! I edited my reverse method in my original question. Please keep in my that my reverse method was only a tester to see where my iterator had trouble. The issue my code is having against the tester is highlighted with ***

Comment: I have added the show me method to the body of the original question. Just as a heads up, the showMe method is also a tester method that was made to see how my code reacted to the tester code.

Comment: @ShermanBachar your showMe() method only prints out the indexes... you will get the same issue as the reverse method if you swap it with storage[i]. There are fundamental issues in your code, I think you should provide the whole code-snippet.

Comment: @ShermanBachar Additionally in addFirst() you are using greater than instead of less than, again....

Comment: That was a stupid mistake on my part for the addFirst() but now it seems to have effected my remove. I have posted my entire code on pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/qFDh5upS  and the tester can be found here: http://pastebin.com/K9Mqkjm9

Comment: @ShermanBachar as I already mentioned, there is something wrong with that for-loop in addFirst(), consider debugging what happens in each iteration of several for-loops in your code. I've edited in my answer what I think you want to achieve with that for-loop.

Comment: it seems that i am now getting issues with my remove method. Does my remove look right to you?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you handle existing content in your addFirst method and the use of growStorage.

```
public void addFirst(E obj) {
    if(currentSize==maxSize)
        growStrorage();

    if(isEmpty())
        storage[1]=obj;

    for(int i=1; i>currentSize+1; i++){
        storage[i+1]=storage[i];
    }

    storage[1]=obj;
    modCounter++;
    currentSize++;
}
```

When you copy the storage, you have to keep a reference to the current storage to copy the current content. You should also use [System.arrayCopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-) rather than copying content by hand. Something like:

```
/**
 * Grows the backing storage and optionally shifts all the content
 * when copying to new array.
 */
private void growStorage(int shift) {
    final Object[] current = storage;
    //double current size
    storage = new Object[current.length * 2];
    maxSize = storage.length;

    System.arrayCopy(current, 0, storage, shift, current.length);
}

public void addFirst(E obj) {
    if(currentSize==maxSize)
        growStrorage(1);

    storage[1]=obj;

    modCounter++;
    currentSize++;
}
```

Comment: what is the System.arrayCopy part do?

Comment: It copies the content from the existing array to the new array. Read the linked javadoc for how the method works.

Comment: for this assignment, I have to manually copy the arrays to a new array,  I have posted my entire code on pastebin here: pastebin.com/qFDh5upS and the tester can be found here: pastebin.com/K9Mqkjm9

Comment: Then copy the data by hand from one array to the other. The important piece is that you must maintain a reference to the "old" array after you have created the new array in order to copy values from old to new.